# Why was this question closed?

Tags: discussion

(Just so I can figure out what's wrong on SO and what's not...)

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153422/why-do-nix-programs-use-so-many-files-closed), and literally within 2 minutes, it was closed as "subjective and argumentative". Why?

"Subjective" makes no sense, since there must be a clear reason for this -- it's consistent among a wide variety of programs.

"Argumentative" also doesn't make sense to me, for the same reason: there's *gotta* be a good reason.

So why was my question closed? Was it really subjective and argumentative? How/why?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, you asked a question that can't be reasonably answered by any one source. No one, except the development team behind a specific application would be able to supply you with an answer to the question, for their specific application. If not flame bait, the question would be too localized.

Also, the question reads like a rant. Questions work well when they are to the point and specific.

Comment: Hm... but then, could you explain why there's 3 "reopen" votes and also a delete vote at the same time? It seems like the people who closed it just didn't want to discuss it, but that there's plenty of people like me who do want to discuss it... :\

Comment: @Mehrdad Most likely sympathy votes because it's been posted here. Since it doesn't fall in the SO scope it will get opened and reopened until a mid eventually kills it.

Comment: Sympathy votes? okay... lol. Hm.. what do you mean by "it's been posted here"? Did someone else also post something about this on meta?

Comment: @Mehrdad. You did. It normally draws people to a question. I have flagged it to be burned though, even in your comments your proving why the question is to be deleted. Your arguing. You don't want to know why, you just want an excuse to argue with others over whether or not it should have been written the way it was. Honestly, with your rep on SO, I would expect you to be more careful in posting questions.